# How to develop mobile application using CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I wanted to develop the mobile application using CodeIgniter. Is it possible.

Web application is already built on CodeIgniter

Comment: you should do it carefully and planing before coding

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a new controller and add appropriate routes.  When I had to do this, I just used a controller that inherited from my primary site controller and added these routes to my routes config (Mine was located in `/system/application/config/routes.php`.  Yours also may look different and this code snippet assumes you have a `page` function):

```
$route['mobile/(:any)'] = "site/mobile/page/$1";
$route['mobile'] = "site/mobile/page/home";
```

Then you'll want to add a rule to your htaccess file to ensure anything going to m.example.com/whatever gets directed to the right path (e.g. /mobile/whatever).

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (^mobile\.|^m\.)(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php/mobile/$1 [L]
```

From there it should route into your mobile controller.  Form me this was in `/site/controllers/mobile.php`.  My primary site controller was `/site/controllers/site.php`

You'll want to recreate whatever logic you use in your site controller in you mobile one excluding desktop assets and including mobile ones and rendering your pages appropriately.  Unfortunately that's about all I understand of the process.  It was mostly my coworker's work that got the mobile controller working and I only used it once or twice, but this should work.

Comment: Hi Joseph, Is this similar to responsive. I would like to develope pure android and iphone mobile app. want to place it on any of the play store.

Comment: Oh... Well that's a whole other beast.  Codeigniter is a web application framework.  It's not suited for native app development.  You can create an API for ajax calls, but not build an app in Codeigniter.  If it needs to be built in HTML, I would suggest looking up PhoneGap or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is posibble. It all depends on your strategy. If you decide to go with Responsive Design, codeigniter makes no difference. If you decide on Adaptive you shoul read the about codeigniter's user-agent library - 
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/user_agent.html

To read about RWD and AWD visit http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/web-designer/what-is-the-difference-between-responsive-vs-adaptive-web-design/

Comment: I would like develope android app and need to place it on google play store. The application is already responsive.

Comment: To post an app on playstore you have to compile to an apk - native android app. You need something else, like PhoneGap....